# Apply CellTemplate to DataGrid bound to dynamic DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, syncfusion, celltemplate

My application builds a datatable (rows & column) at runtime, so the columns/properties are variable.
Now I'm displaying it in a datagrid & trying to set CellTemplate and unsuccessfully binding each cell value. It shows values correctly before applying the CellTemplates...

Here's the code I'm building the datagrid with & designating cell styles:

```
 private void BuildDataGridColumnsFromDataTable(DataTable dT)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn dTColumn in dT.Columns) 
        {
            var binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding(dTColumn.ToString());

            DataTemplate dt = null;
            if (dTColumn.ColumnName == "Country")
            {
                GridTextColumn textColumn = new GridTextColumn();
                textColumn.MappingName = "Country";
                textColumn.Width = 100;

                MatrixDataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
            }
            else
            {
                dt = (DataTemplate)Resources["NameTemplate"];
                GridTextColumn textColumn = new GridTextColumn();
                textColumn.MappingName = dTColumn.ColumnName;
                textColumn.CellTemplate = dt;

                MatrixDataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
            }
        }
    }
```

And a cell style. I've been unable to retreive each datatable cell value. So for instance here I'd just take the original datatable cell values & bind/display them in each datagrid textblock.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate">
        <TextBlock Name="NameTextBlock" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}, Converter={StaticResource drvc}}" 
                   Text="{Binding}" Background="LightGreen"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

----EDIT---

I'm able to achieve it by building a datatemplate in code-behind & passing the runtime created column(property) like this:

```
textColumn.CellTemplate = GetDataTemplate(dTColumn.ColumnName);
```

I'd much prefer building this in XAML though... so what I'm really needing is to pass the column parameter to XAML. Any ideas how to best achieve this would be very much appreciated!

```
        private static DataTemplate GetDataTemplate(string col) 
    {
        DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory txtBox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
        txtBox.SetValue(TextBox.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center);
        txtBox.SetValue(TextBox.BackgroundProperty, (Brush)(new BrushConverter()).ConvertFromString("#9EB11C"));
        template.VisualTree = txtBox;

        System.Windows.Data.Binding bind = new System.Windows.Data.Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath(col), //Provides the column (property) at runtime.
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
        };

        // Third: set the binding in the text box
        txtBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);

        return template;
    }
```

Comment: You're binding the TextBlock's DataContext directly to the DataGridCell itself, aren't you supposed to bind to its DataContext?

Comment: I've tried {Binding DataContext} & {Binding Content}, both of which return empty. Since the datatable columns are produced at runtime, I can't specify the exact "property" to bind to like usual.

Comment: Edit above shows how I could achieve this from code behind by passing the column as a parameter. But I'm looking for a XAML solution.

Comment: Maybe you can try `DataGridView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so what I'm really needing is to pass the column parameter to XAML

I am afraid there is no "XAML solution" to bind to a property whose name is not known at build time. After all XAML is a markup language.

So you will have to create a `DataTemplate` per column programmatically and dynamically like you are currently doing in your `GetDataTemplate` method. You cannot do something like `Text="{Binding [DynamicValue]}"` in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [forum](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/139102/converting-a-customized-quotdatagridboundcolumnquot-solution-to-syncfusion) to bind underlying data object dynamically to the property of the control during the DataTemplate creation in code behind.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thanks Deivaselvan. This does help for a code-behind solution. I was looking for a way to utilize XAML for the datatemplates here, which I understand is not possible.